# Are searchable maps limited to geocoding APIs like Google

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, mapbox, api

My client wants a searchable map. I'd like to use Leaflet and Mapbox for the map, but is having an address-search feature limited to  geocoding APIs like Google Maps or Mapquest?

Comment: Have a look at Leaflet geocoding plugins: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely have a search feature in your map.  As commented by TomazicM:

> *Have a look at Leaflet geocoding plugins: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding*

My favorite is the [esri-leaflet-geosearch](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-geocoder) plugin.

Comment: In response to your "meta" question, no it is not wrong to answer when someone else has put the same in a comment.  Answers should be posted as answers, not as comments, and it is fairly common to see short answers that start with something like "as commented by TomazicM..."